# Maven GroupId with special characters

Tags: maven, dns

One best practice for choosing the Maven groupId says to choose the groupId according to the domain name of the company. Some domain names contain special characters, especially hyphen-minus. And moreover with the new non-ASCII-domains a domain name can also contain non-ASCII-characters.

Now my questions:

1. Can I use the minus in the groupId? What are reasonable alternatives?
2. How do I handle special characters of non-ASCII domain names in the groupId?
3. A concrete problem: I have to find groupIds for three independent companies:
   Company A's domain is "heccare.de"
   Company B's domain is "heccare-international.de"
   Company C's domain is "heccare-int.de"

What are reasonable groupIds?

Comment: "Can I use the minus in the groupId?" - what happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 5):

Per Oracle's [documentation on package naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), hyphens (namely, `-`) in DNS names should be replaced with underscores (namely, `_`), names that begin with a number should be pre-underscored (so `me.123.com` becomes `com._123.me`), and names that conflict with a reserved keyword should be post-underscored (so `int.me.com` becomes `com.me.int_`).

Unicode characters are fine, as per the [spec for identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) (for instance, `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart('é')` evaluates to `true`).

Your group names would canonically be `de.heccare`, `de.heccare_international`, and `de.heccare_int`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Using your domain name as a groupID is not a bad idea, but it's not necessary. JUnit's groupID is simply "junit":

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've seen other groupIDs that are a combination of domain name, and something more descriptive, such as `com.mycompany.webapi`, `com.mycompany.wslib`, `com.mycompany.database.util` etc... of course, the only thing that resolves to an actual domain is `mycompany.com` but I don't think that's a problem.

And as for special characters, the dash is OK (just noticed that I have a dependency on Apache Commons I/O, whose groupID is "commons-io") , but non-ASCII characters, you'll just have to try and see!